# How to set default value to dc selectMenu

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have to set a default value to `selectMenu` so suppose if I have A, B, C in my select box, I want to select "A" as default. Is this possible?

I am having a multiple `selectMenu` and using `selectMenu.filters()` to get the selected values.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4r7vnbc/1/)**

```
var data = [
    { Activity: "A", Count: 10},
    { Activity: "B", Count: 20},
    { Activity: "C", Count: 30},
    { Activity: "D", Count: 40},
    { Activity: "E", Count: 50},
]

var ndx  = crossfilter(data);
var dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d["Activity"]; });
var group = dim.group().reduceCount();


select = dc.selectMenu("#my-select-menu");

select
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(group)
    .multiple(true)
    .controlsUseVisibility(true);

dc.renderAll();
```

Also I was wondering if somehow is it possible to not show a box but a dropdown for multi-select?

Comment: I've never used dc.js but glancing at the docs/related questions, to pre-select a value, you can try using `.filter("A")`. And for your second question, a box will be shown for **select** with `multiple` or `size` options by default. To switch to a dropdown, you can switch to using an API like [bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) or [Select2](https://select2.org/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing bootstrap Select option. I also thought `filter("A")` should work but it doesn't.

Comment: `replaceFilter` solved the issue, will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue using `replaceFilter` like this:

```
select.replaceFilter([["A"]]).redrawGroup();
```

Note the syntax, it's array inside array.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4r7vnbc/10/)**

Comment: Yes, that's a confusing feature of dc.js, unclear why it works that way. Thanks for following up!